# How to print os.args[1:] without braces in Go?

Tags: go

When I tried to print command line arguments using

```
    fmt.Println(os.Args[1:])
```

I got result like

```
[Gates Bill]
```

How can I get rid of the `[]` around the arguments? And `Go` seems to eat all the commas in the arguments, how can I get the output like

```
Last name, First name
Gates, Bill
```

Comment: `for k,v := range os.Args[1:]`?

Comment: @u_mulder If I want to output `Knuth, Donald, Author of The Art of Computer Programming.` while `Knuth, Donald` is the user input, I cannot figure out how.

Comment: @Nick is it important to separate on every two inputs? i.e. is it possible your user will call with `./myapp Knuth Donald Gates Bill`?

Answer (score 10):

You should use [`strings.Join`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) for this. Try,

```
fmt.Printf("%s, Author of The Art of Computer Programming", strings.Join(os.Args[1:], ", "))
```

`Join` returns a `string` with `", "` inserted between each argument.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's outputting the brackets is because you're passing a slice into the print command.

What you want to do is take each command and put them into a string to be printed as needed.

```
firstname := os.Args[1]
lastname := os.Args[2]
fmt.Println(lastname + ", " + firstname)
```

You should also take a look at the **strings** package as was pointed out by Chandru. There's a bunch of goodies in there to help with dealing with strings.

See: https://golang.org/pkg/strings/